# Slow Performance in Data Scraping Function When Both Image and Video Not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Python program that scrapes a significant amount of data from web pages. However, I'm encountering a performance issue with a specific function within the program. This function is responsible for extracting either a video or an image URL from a given HTML element. It seems to be running very slowly, taking over 10 minutes to complete when both the video and image are not found in the HTML code.

```
def _get_video_or_img(self, desc_element: WebElement) -> str:
    try:
        video = self._wait.until(lambda d:
                                 desc_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'video')).get_attribute("src")
        return video
    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        try:
            image = self._wait.until(lambda d:
                                     desc_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self._css_image_locator))\
                .get_attribute("src")
            return image
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            self._pprint_overrider(status=f"Both video and image not found: {e}", info_type=3, logs=True)
        except Exception as e:
            self._pprint_overrider(status=f"An error occurred while finding image: {e}", info_type=3, logs=True)
    except Exception as e:
        self._pprint_overrider(status=f"An error occurred while finding video: {e}", info_type=3, logs=True)
    return self._not_available
```

To provide some context, when either the video or image is found, the function performs reasonably well. However, when both the video and image are not found, it takes an unexpectedly long time (up to 10 minutes).

I've tried to handle exceptions and errors, but I can't seem to pinpoint the root cause of this performance issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to improve the performance of this function would be greatly appreciated.

Note: some protected variables

```
self._wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
self._css_image_locator = "a > div > img[alt]"
self._not_available = "Not available"
```

Saved Logs:

```
Status: ERROR: Both video and image not found: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a > div > img[alt]"}
  (Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.141); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B237C3+48947]
    (No symbol) [0x00AB8551]
    (No symbol) [0x009BC92D]
    (No symbol) [0x009E9E38]
    (No symbol) [0x009E9EFB]
    (No symbol) [0x009E2F61]
    (No symbol) [0x00A050D4]
    (No symbol) [0x009E2EB6]
    (No symbol) [0x00A053E4]
    (No symbol) [0x00A175DA]
    (No symbol) [0x00A04E86]
    (No symbol) [0x009E16C7]
    (No symbol) [0x009E284D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D6FDF9+2458985]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DB744F+2751423]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DB1361+2726609]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BA0680+560624]
    (No symbol) [0x00AC238C]
    (No symbol) [0x00ABE268]
    (No symbol) [0x00ABE392]
    (No symbol) [0x00AB10B7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76857D59+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7734B79B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x7734B71F+191]
```

Comment: what time is set for explicit and implicit waiting? And your code looks very complex

Comment: Yes, indeed, this code is complex and quite large. That is why I cannot post the full code here. The wait time is mentioned in protected variables, which is 2.